# Add Android Run/Debug configuration for Flutter project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am working with a Flutter [example project](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/flutter_view) where it shows how to share a FlutterView inside an Android application (and iOS also).

While working with it I tried this:

I make changes to the android project like changing the theme color, if I do hot-reload/run for `main.dart` I don't see the changes reflected in the running app. I have to stop it from Android Studio and run the `main.dart` again to see the changes.

To solve the issue I was thinking to add a `run/debug configuration` for Android `app` module. So that I could run android `app` and not `main.dart`.

Is there a way how to achieve this in Android Studio?

One solution for me was to open the `android`(/flutter_view/android/app) project from a new window in Android studio. I could run the app this way.

(But here I encountered another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066094/wrong-project-structure-is-shown-for-flutter-android-module-in-as) in case anyone has the solution).

Answer (score 11):

According to my understanding you face problems when you open your project and try to run.
Android studio asks you to configure your project to be able to run...

It's easy to solve near to run button you will find "add configuration" button just press then from left side select "flutter" and put in the field "entrypoint" your main Dart file path main.dart...
EX. E:/project/lib/main.dart....

Then from top right corner press "create configuration"...
That's it.

Answer (score 0):

For Configure your Flutter app on Android you have to Upgrade Gradle file..

So Go to the Tool and at you will find AGP upgrade Assistant..
It Download new Gradle file then its Config automatic..